# Oracle view less than doesnt work in linked-server query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I'am using a linked-server in my SQL-server to query an oracle database.

There is a view on Oracle side: article_test having a simple where condition creationdate < '01.01.2019'

Unfortuanately there is no result at the SQL-server query

```
select * from [LINKDB]..[SCHEMA].[ARTICLE_TEST]
```

Setting the where condition to greater than creationdate > '01.01.2019'

everything is fine and there is a result.

there must be an issue regarding the "less than" condition.

Comment: Try the same on the Oracle server directly. SQL Server does not interpret or execute the view in any way (it leaves that to the remote side), so the fact that you're dealing with a linked server ought to be irrelevant. If that *does* make a difference, that would be interesting, but otherwise there's no reason to assume the problem isn't just with your data or your query. On the other hand, if the `WHERE` clause is on the *SQL Server end*, which your question doesn't make clear, use a date format that isn't dependent on locale (`20190101`).

Comment: Running the same query on oracle server directly works. There is a result with less than. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Then you should probably check the type of `creationdate` as SQL Server sees it: `SELECT TOP(1) SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(creationdate, 'BaseType') FROM ...article_test`. If it is not a date/time type, then comparing is happening through string comparisons, and that will obviously not work for anything other than `YYYYMMdd` formats. If it is a date/time type on the Oracle end, the issue may then be with conversions in the driver.

Comment: Also, SQL Server has limited support for date/time literals, but you could try those to see if the driver likes them better for remoting purposes: `{ts '2019-01-01 00:00:00'}` (an explicit `CAST('20190101' AS DATETIME)` would also do). Otherwise, it might be sending over a string to Oracle which Oracle then does not properly convert.

Comment: If `CREATIONDATE` is a date column, why are you comparing a date to a character string? If `CREATIONDATE` is not a date column, why are you storing dates as strings? ???

Comment: Hi have you try for use OpenQuery ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017      https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-linked-server-without-openquery